# Authentication exception with elasticsearch5

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elk

I receive the following exception AuthenticationException: TransportError(401, '')
when executing

```
from elasticsearch5 import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch('server', send_get_body_as='POST')
es.search()
```

Warning: POST 'server'+'index'/_search
However, I can access the server through browser with the url above in the warning.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? What is the warning about? What url are you referring to?

Comment: @Mirronelli The warning says:"POST http://....//_search [status:401 request: 0.xxx s]" and if I click on the url, I can see the data.